# Postgresql Php extension

Tags: php, postgresql

I have installed the module with php ( `./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`), but I obtain one more time the same error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect(). In my configuration file of php, `php.ini`, the postgresql `pdo_pgsql` module appears as loaded:

```
pdo_pgsql
---------

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.3.4
Module version  1.0.2
Revision    $Id$
```

Answer (score 0):

`pdo_pgsql` is the PostgreSQL driver for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

If you need `pg_connect`, you should install the [PostgreSQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php).